# T and S are invertible and why (ST) is invertible too?

Tags: linear-transformations

I have functions T and S such that T : V -> V  and S : V->V

and S and T are invertible.

Prove why composition of (ST) is invertible too.

I tried to figure it out by letting TS=ST, and TS and ST are linear.

but I am stuck...

Comment: Try with $\;T^{-1}S^{-1}\;$, though this question belongs more in set theory than in linear algebra.

Comment: @Timbuc Why do you say this belongs in set theory? This is a standard exercise in linear algebra..

Comment: @Cameron, because in basic set theory, which usually preceedes linear algebra, it is proved that composition of invertible functions is invertible (when domains and ranges fit accordingly, of course). The exercise I know in linear algebra is to make sure the condition of $\;T\;$ invertible iff $\;\ker T=0\;$ is fulfilled (in the finite dimensional case, of course).

Comment: @Timbuc While true, most people do not take set theory prior to having linear algebra and do not see things so generally.

Comment: They don't? Well, where I am from you see set theory even in high school.

Comment: @Timbuc Interesting! Would you by any chance be from Germany?

Comment: Nop @Cameron: Israel.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: A map (on a finite dimensional vector space) is invertible if and only if it has trivial nullspace, i.e. if $Ax = 0$, then $x = 0$. What can you say about the nullspace of $ST$ with respect to the nullspaces of $S$ and $T$?

To show that $(ST)^{-1} = T^{-1}S^{-1}$, try multiplying $ST$ and $T^{-1}S^{-1}$. What do you get?

Comment: just to make sure, For this transformation, does commutative hold? I mean ST=TS?

Comment: It does not have to hold and in general will not.

Comment: Hmm,, I can't see the point.. T(x)=0 when x=0 and S(T(X))=0 when T(x)=0, does that mean that ST has also zero nullspace..?

Comment: Yep. That's more or less the right reasoning. What do you conclude about $ST$ from that?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, your first line is missing "in the finite dimensional case", I believe.

Comment: @Timbuc You're right of course. I don't want to confuse OP with the nitty gritty of infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: So ST is invertible because it is 0 only when x=0?

Comment: @aaa Exactly right :)

Comment: And there is another part, where I have to show invertible of ST is same as inverse of T and inverse of S,like T-1S-1 (-1 is a notation of inverse for each function)

Comment: I am confused because TS is not same as ST, does that mean that invertible of ST is not same as invertible of TS?

Comment: @aaa That is correct. The inverse of $ST$ and the inverse of $TS$ need not be the same. I have updated my answer to give you a hint for this part.

Comment: @Artem Given that the OP talks about linearity and the tag is linear transformations, I would disagree.

Comment: CameronWilliams I removed my comment after noticing the tag. However, as @Timbuc noted, this questions does not belong to the realm of the linear algebra and definitely does not require referencing to nullspaces.

Answer (score 2):

**Set Theoretic Approach**. This can be generalized to $T: V \to W$ and $g : W \to U.$

Injectivity:

\begin{align}
STx = STy &\implies Tx = Ty \quad \text{because $S$ is injective.}\\
&\implies x = y \quad \text{because $T$ is injective.}
\end{align}

Surjectivity:

Suppose $v \in V$; since $S$ is surjective, $\exists b \in V$ such that $v = Sb$. As $b \in V$, then by the surjectivity of $T$, $\exists a \in V$ such that $b = Ta$. Hence we immediately see that for any $v \in V$, there exists $a \in V$ such that $v = Sb = STa$.

**Determinant**:

There is also a way to see this through determinants, that is $$0 \neq c = \det T \det S = \det TS .$$

Comment: I think you mean $STy$, not $TSy$ in showing injectivity.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, yes I did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proof has two distinct aspects.

1. If $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are any invertible (= bijective) maps between sets, then their composition $g\circ f:A\to C$ is always also invertible. The inverse is the composition of $\def\'{^{-1}}g\':C\to B$ and $f\':B\to A$, in other words $(g\circ f)\'=f\'\circ g\'$. This part is completely general and has no specific relation to linear algebra.
2. If a map between vector spaces $T:V\to W$ is both linear and bijective (invertible as a map of sets), then the inverse map of sets $f\':W\to V$ is also *linear*. This is a pure linear algebra fact that should be one of the first things to know about invertible linear maps. It's proof looks a bit tricky, but it you think of it is quite natural (use the linearity of $f$ in the opposite sense, after inserting back-and-forth maps to make $f$ appear in the first place):
   $$
     f\'(\lambda w_1+\mu w_2)
    =f\'\bigl(\lambda f(f\'(w_1))+\mu f(f\'(w_2))\bigr)
    =f\'\bigl( f\bigl(\lambda f\'(w_1)+\mu f\'(w_2)\bigr)\bigr)
    =\lambda f\'(w_1)+\mu f\'(w_2).
   $$

Now all that is left is apply it to your situation: $ST$ in a bijective map (1) with inverse $T\'S\'$, and (2) this inverse is a linear map (since you checked that $ST$ is linear).